# Compare each element in CSV with other using python

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv

I want to compare each element in a csv file with all other elements using python. I have made 2 columns which are exacly same thinking I can iterate over each row.col pair.
File  looks like this

NAME  NAME_COMPARE
AAA    AAA
BBB    BBB

The output I would like to see is:
AAA,AAA
AAA,BBB
BBB,AAA
BBB,BBB

here is the code I am using

```
fname = 'UA_TEST.csv'
fp = open(fname)
fp.next()
cscrd = (csv.reader(fp, delimiter='\t', doublequote=True))
for row in cscrd:
    a = row[1]
    for row in cscrd:
        b = row[2]
    print a,b
```

Code gives following output

AAA,AAA
AAA,BBB

and then it exits it never goes through the second loop.

Any pointers?

Answer (score 1):

I think you need something like this,

```
import csv

fname = 'UA_TEST.csv'
fp = open(fname)
fp.next()
cscrd = (csv.reader(fp, delimiter='\t', doublequote=True))
i = 0
for row in cscrd:
    a = row[i]
    for col in row:
        b = col
        print a,b
    i += 1
```

This gives the output:

```
AAA AAA
AAA BBB
BBB AAA
BBB BBB
```